# How do I access this key in a json object? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, json

I have a function that accesses the Twitch.tv API to retrieve various information about a live stream. When I try to retrieve the "game" key for a stream which is online it simply returns "undefined", although if I access the developer console I can see the logged json object includes the proper game key. How do I properly access the game key?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xq0t6.png)

**My function:**

```
$("#usernamelookupcheck").on("click", function() {
    $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/" + $("#usernamelookup").val(), function(json) {
        if (json["error"] == "Not Found") {
            $streamstatus2 = "User does not exist!";
            $("#lookupresult").html("User does not exist!");
        } else {
            $.getJSON("https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/" + $("#usernamelookup").val(), function(json) {
                $currentgame = json["game"];
                if (json["stream"] === null) {
                    $streamstatus2 = "Offline";
                } else {
                    $streamstatus2 = "Online" + "<br><br>";
                    console.log(json);
                };
                $("#lookupresult").html("<br><br> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <strong>Status: " + $streamstatus2 + "</strong><br><br>" + $currentgame);

            });

        };
    })
});
```

Comment: It's `json.stream.game`, provided your screenshot shows the result of logging `json`

Comment: I noticed there is a property called `stream_type` and it has a value of `live`. Maybe that is also an indicator to whether a stream is online or not?

Comment: @SamuelToh That might be it, I might implement that in the near future to make the code more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use

`json['stream']['game']`  or `json.stream.game`